# Which kind of join should i use? [EF4.0 code first ]

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

i apologize for the bad topic title as i am kinda at lost of what should i do here.

First of all, here are my database table designs and i would like to receive some sort of feedback as well before proceeding:

I am trying to make an enrollment web application.

**Subjects**

```
subject
[id] [subj]   [professor]  [cstart]  [cend]  [days]  [count] [units]
1   comalgo    carl        10:00am  12:30pm  M-W      40      3.0
2   compasm    carl        01:00pm  02:30pm  T-TH     40      3.0
3   compro     miguel      04:30pm  06:30pm  M-W      35      3.0
4   pro5       fua         03:30pm  05:30pm  T-TH     30      3.0
5   pro5       fua         06:30pm  08:30pm  F        10      3.0
```

**Students**

```
students
[id] [fname]   [lname]   [bday]       [unitsleft]  [unitstaken] [major]
 1    carlos    doe      11/20/1990      100           0         BS-COMPUTER SCIENCE
 2    miguel    doe      08/15/1992      100           0         BS-ECONOMY
 3    carl      doe      12/12/1991      100           0         BS-PSYCHOLOGY
 4    test      doe      02/12/1992      100           0         BS-LITERATURE
```

What i plan on doing is that, the subjects will be presented through a series of list and the student will pick multiple subjects and enroll. The total enrolled units should not be greater than 20 and less than 11. I already implemented that part and i am now working on storing the selected subjects.

Here is my proposed solution and i would like to receive some feedbacks about it and what operation should i use.

I will have a centralized table for all of enrolled subjects

**Enrolled subjects**

```
selected subject
[id] [subjid] [studentid] [status]
1       1        1           P     //comalgo enrolled by carlos, P is for pending grade
2       1        2           P     //comalgo enrolled by miguel  P is for pending grade
3       2        1           P     //compasm enrolled by carlos  P is for pending grade
```

What i plan to happen is that: i have a profile page for the students and they will be able to view/edit their currently enrolled subjects specifically for themselves(based from ID)

I want them to be presented with the following table headers which is based from the enrolled subjects:

`[subj] [professor] [cstart] [cend] [days]`

Here are the brief summary of my questions:

1.) is my table alright? or it's a bad design?
  2.) What kind of method should i use? i am trying to research about it(joins) but i am somehow confused and in need of clarification. I want to present the users with their selected subjects.

**edit:** i think i can do something like.. select where id = x from the `enrolled subjects` then get the `subject id` but i am not sure if that will be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables look good (i.e. third normal form). An INNER join will do

```
SELECT
    B.subj, B.professor, B.cstart, B.cend, B.days
FROM
    selectedsubjects A
    INNER JOIN subjects B ON A.subjid = B.id
WHERE
    A.studentid = 1
```

---

p.s. This looks like an assignment for school or something out of a book...?

Comment: Oh no, it was just a personal project to test myself and i will try what you did, thanks for the feedback and for the answer :D

Comment: Another thing, what if i wanted to display the `status` as well?

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

```
var query =  context.EnrolledSubjects
   .Include("Subject")
   .Where(i => i.StudentId == 1)
   .Select(i => new {
      i.Subject.Subj,
      i.Subject.Professor,
      i.Subject.CsStart,
      i.Subject.Send,
      i.Subject.Days,
      i.Status
};
```

Comment: oh nice, thank you. i will try it later. Is this the lambda equivalent from the post above? `Subject` is the name of the table right?

Comment: Yeah, `Subject` is the navigation property on the `EnrolledSubject`. If you have some problem, update your answer with the structure of your classes

Comment: One more thing, do i need to make another class to hold the result list? since i am planning on passing it on a view.

Comment: It is not necessary. I created an object, but not another class. See that I used `var` and `Select`. It will hold all these properties in an anonymous type. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx. However, if you want to pass the result on a view, it is better to create another class.